# Italic equation numbers for \IEEEeqnarray within theorem

Tags: ieeetran, italic, tags

**Edit**: I have changed the question to use a minimal example.

When I use an `\IEEEeqnarray` inside of an italicized `theorem` environment, the equation numbers (tags) also become italicized. The same thing does not happen for a regular equation, as the below image shows.
What might be the cause of this, and any ideas on how to fix it?

The issue is not present if the `IEEEtran` class is used instead of the `IEEEtrantools` package.

[image: Minimal example]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
    Employing novel methods by Craquepot et al, we show that
    \begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
        1 + 2 &=& 4, \\
        1 + 2 &=& 5.
    \end{IEEEeqnarray}
    This is in contrast to an earlier conjecture by the ancient Babylonians,
    \begin{equation}
        1 + 2 = 3.
    \end{equation}
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.  You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: I couldn't find ieeetraantools.sty, but I did find ieeetran.cls [onecolumn].  It worked fine (no italic equation numbers).

Comment: Thanks for your corrections. I have replaced the old example with a minimal one. The problem only appears with IEEEtrantools, not with IEEEtran.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug in IEEEtrantools, which can be fixed easily. The error is in the definition of `\theequationdis`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

% we want normal font for the equation number
\renewcommand\theequationdis{\normalfont\normalcolor(\theequation)}     

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Employing novel methods by Craquepot et al, we show that
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
1 + 2 &=& 4, \\
1 + 2 &=& 5.
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
This is in contrast to an earlier conjecture by the ancient Babylonians,
\begin{equation}
1 + 2 = 3.
\end{equation}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The corresponding line in `IEEEtran.cls` is

```
\def\theequationdis{{\normalfont \normalcolor (\theequation)}}% (1)
```

but the definition in `IEEEtrantools.sty` misses `\normalfont` and `\normalcolor`.

Comment: In case you use `\IEEEyessubnumber`, you might also want to add
`\renewcommand\theIEEEsubequationdis{\normalfont\normalcolor(\theIEEEsubequation)}`