# How to change the equation number style to italic

Tags: equations, italic, number

The equation number style is always normalfont, how can I change it to *italic font* such as (*1.1*)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Please help us help you by adding a MWE https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that.

Comment: I think that the user want something like this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369075/italic-equation-numbers-for-ieeeeqnarray-within-theorem

Answer (score 4):

Quite simple with the `\newtagform` command from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\newtagform{italic}[\textit]{(}{)}
\usetagform{italic}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{2}
\begin{equation}
\label{demo}
x = y + z
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it works well

Answer (score 1):

In OpTeX, you can define `\_thednum` internal macro:

```
\fontfam[lmfonts]

\def\_thednum {{\it (\_the\_secnum.\_the\_dnum)}}


\sec First section

$$
  A = B \eqmark[myeq]
$$
This is equation \ref[myeq].

\bye
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!